# RPi 2 SD card becomes write-protected

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, pi-2

I'm using Raspbian, and after some uptime (less than an hour) the root filesystem suddenly becomes readonly. Here is a console log of checking whether the SD card write protection is turned on, and trying to remount the filesystem with read-write access:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ touch asd
touch: cannot touch `asd': Read-only file system
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo ./sdtool-rpi /dev/mmcblk0 status                                                                                                                 
[+] Found RCA for /dev/mmcblk0: AAAA.
[+] Card CSD: 400E005A5B5900003B377F800A404079.
[+] Write protection state: Off.
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /
mount: cannot remount block device /dev/mmcblk0p2 read-write, is write-protected
pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

After a reboot everything is back to normal for some time. How could I solve this problem? Could this be a dead SD card?

Comment: `sdtool-rpi` does not seem to be standard package. Are you doing something to access the SDcard?

Comment: As I said after a reboot everything is functioning normally for some time. I used `wget` to download `sdtool-rpi`.

Comment: If you're still an active user, paste the last 500 lines of `dmesg` into your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `mount` command on its own - you will possibly find your root partition is marked, in the last group of words (in side parentheses like these), something beginning with `(ro,...)` whereas you would expect it to be `(rw,...)`!  This is highly likely to mean that a file system error was detected and the standard kernel behaviour in this case (for a faulty FS) is to mark the file-system **READ-ONLY** to prevent further "corruption" {you may actually see the setting for that as the option `errors=remount-ro` in the same area of the output from mount on other actual file-systems}.

An, ahem, *"not suitable"*,  Flash card is *one* possible cause of this type of error - though I venture to suggest it is not the only one!  For example, even with journalled file-system types such as Ext4, it is not a good idea to remove power from a *nix system without flushing any pending writes out to the file-system - this is one of the steps that the `shutdown` command will do as appropriate (I wanted to quote the *nix man page for `shutdown(8)` to point out the `-n` option which *in the past* said something like:

> -n  - bring the system down, quickly, by ourself - the system unit is ON FIRE!

but the standard text now just says it is "discouraged" to use that option. 8-P )

Recovery of the root partition is a bit more fraught than other cases because the fix requires running `fsck` on the file-system which needs to be (IIRC must be) **not** mounted at the time.  If you have a PC with a card reader and a Linux installation there it is easiest to use *that* to repair the SD card - *(Try and prevent the SD card from being automatically mounted when you insert it into the PC as you´ĺl only have to un-mount it to do the same `fsck` on it!)* - once you have identified the added "disk" in your PC has the faulty partition/file-system.

Comment: Probably a corrupted fs was the problem, I reflashed the SD card, and now it works.

Comment: I  have similar issue, and I tried several tools already even  on mac and windows and nothing helped, it still says that the sdCard is read only.

Comment: Ah, but Windows only sees the __first__ partition on SDCards and that is usually a FAT one which isn't the partition/file-system that is used for `/` in Linux... A Mac might detect all the partitions but it might not show them in its fancy GUI - I am not terribly familiar with that OS...

Answer (score 1):

Long story short and based on the console output you provided, your SD card might be broken. I have an SD card that does exactly this.

If that's not the case, have you checked for anything that might remount the system as read-only?